# How do I call a static method defined in one script from another script?

Tags: groovy

I have a method defined in the file "shared.groovy" like this:

```
def static configure()
{
    .....
}
```

And I have another script file in the same dir, where I need to call the configure() method. I'm trying it this way

```
shared.configure()
```

but getting this exception:

```
FATAL: No such property: shared for class: script14095498929361009943305
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: shared for class: script14095498929361009943305
```

Another ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to load the file first.

I only know two ways to dynamically load groovy at runtime

1. closures (Have the following syntax:  {inoutput,inoutput2 ->  //Yourprocessing using the input&output params }   )

> ```
> def sh = new GroovyShell()  
> File f = new File("Yourfile");  
> def closure = sh.evaluate(f.text);
> ```

1. classes

> ```
> GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
> File f = new File("Yourfile");
> Class tempClass = gcl.parseClass(f);
> tempClass.configure();
> ```

I don't know of any way to parse only a method, that's why I always use one of these approaches (I even created dummyclasses and put my required static methods in it, this works flawless)

Comment: How do I call static methods via this tempClass object?

Comment: as I made it in the example, by calling it with the class directly, instead of Class xyz = new tempClass(); , you call the tempClass directly

Answer (score 7):

One.groovy:

```
static void m1() {
   println 'One'
}
```

Two.groovy

```
One.m1()
```

It works fine.

Comment: Exactly what I did, results in exception. Maybe because classpath is not set to the folder with scripts by an outer application.

Answer (score 1):

This seems fixed in Groovy 2.5.3.  Before that, one would need to `import static shared.configure` (in addition to `import shared`) and only then call `shared.configure()`.